# AS3: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, typeerror

I've been working on a flash game for an assignment and it's been a real headache so far. The game's relatively simple, collect items (mementos), avoid enemies or lose health (sanity), collect all items on the screen to level up (items, player and enemies reset, score remains the same), get hit 5 times and you get the game over screen.

I've having an annoyingly odd error. Getting game over with no items doesn't give any errors and resets the game fine (seemingly), but the issues are:

*Having any items when getting game over results in Error 1009.

*Clicking the exit game button with any items results in Error 1009.

*Collecting all the items should give the "lvlUp" function, but nothing happens, the if statement never triggers.

I've spent a good day or so on this issue and came pretty close to breaking the entire thing a few times, so I decided to consult here with experienced coders.

Apologies in advance for messy code, I've only just started using AS3

Game document class code:

```
package 
{

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import player;

public class Memento extends MovieClip
{
    //importing required variables
    private var onScreenContent:Array;
    private var playerSkill:int;
    private var myXY:Array;
    private var mySpeed:int;
    private var border:Rectangle;
    private var myMaxItems:int;
    private var numItems:int;
    private var numEnemies:int;
    private var maxEnemies:int;
    private var characterMC:player;
    public var sanity:int;
    public var mementos:int;
    public var currentMementos:int;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public function Memento()
    {
        trace("initialising DOS game");
        //simulates a selected skill level  
        playerSkill = 3;
        sanity = 5;
        mementos = 0;
        onScreenContent = new Array  ;
        border = new Rectangle(30,180,870,750);
    }

    //code to add character into game at correct position
    private function addCharacter():void
    {
        trace("Adding the character");
        //set the initial values to character starting pos
        var myXY:Array = [480,900];
        var mySpeed:int = playerSkill + 6;
        //create and add a new player to screen
        characterMC = new player(myXY,border,mySpeed);
        addChild(characterMC);
        characterMC.focusRect = false;
        stage.focus = characterMC;
    }//end function addCharacter
    //code to add items into game
    private function addItems():void
    {
        trace("Initialising items");
        //amount of items
        var myMaxItems:int = playerSkill + 1;
        //adding the items one at a time
        for (var numItem:int = 0; numItem < myMaxItems; numItem++)
        {
            var thisItem:collect = new collect(border,playerSkill,characterMC);
            thisItem.name = "Item";
            //adding item to stage
            onScreenContent.push(thisItem);
            addChild(thisItem);
        }//end for statement
    }//end function addItems
    //code to add enemies into game
    private function addEnemy():void
    {
        trace("Adding Enemies");
        //setting initial number of enemies to match game/skill level
        var maxEnemies:int = playerSkill + 1;
        //adding enemies one by one using a loop
        for (var numEnemies:int = 0; numEnemies < maxEnemies; numEnemies++)
        {
            //creating a new enemy
            var thisEnemy:enemy = new enemy(border,playerSkill,characterMC);
            thisEnemy.name = "Enemy";
            trace("adding enemies to stage");
            onScreenContent.push(thisEnemy);
            addChild(thisEnemy);
        }
    }//end function addEnemy
    //code to update game scores
    public function updateScores(myMC: MovieClip):void
    {
        //change player score if they collide with enemy or item
        mementos +=  myMC.scoreMod;
        sanity +=  myMC.healthMod;
        if (currentMementos == 4)
        {
            trace("lvlup");
            levelUp();
            currentMementos = 0;
        }//end if statement
        if (myMC.name.indexOf("item") != -1)
        {
            var myIndex:int = onScreenContent.indexOf(myMC);
            onScreenContent.splice(myIndex, 1);
            currentMementos++;
        }//end if statement
        trace("updating player score");
        //run updatescores function
        displayScores();
        //run gameover check
        if (sanity <= 0)
        {
            trace("game over prompted");
            gameOver();
        }//end if statement
    }
    //function to update scores
    private function displayScores():void
    {
        //update dynamic text fields
        lifeDisplay.text = "*" + sanity;
        scoreDisplay.text = "Mementos: " + mementos;
        trace("displaying updated scores");
    }
    //function to level up
    private function levelUp():void
    {
        // resetting all items
        clearObjects();
        removeChild(characterMC);
        playerSkill +=  1;
        //resetting game stage
        addCharacter();
        addItems();
        addEnemy();
    }

    public function clearObjects():void
    {
        //removing all remaining game objects
        for each (var myObj in onScreenContent)
        {
            myObj.removeAsset();
            myObj = null;
        }

        // reset the array for next level
        onScreenContent = new Array();
    }

    //function to return from map stage back to main menu
    function exitMap(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop(1);
        //removing player
        removeChild(characterMC);
        clearObjects();
        mementos = 0;
        sanity = 5;
        currentMementos = 0;
    }//end function exitMap
    //function to execute game over
    private function gameOver():void
    {
        //game over script
        trace("game over");
        gotoAndStop(4);
        clearObjects();
        removeChild(characterMC);
        mementos = 0;
        sanity = 5;
        currentMementos = 0;
    }
}//end class
}//end package
```

Enemy class code:

```
package 
{

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class enemy extends MovieClip
{

    private var borderEnemy:Rectangle;
    private var charNum:int;
    private var charSpeed:int;
    private var charDir:int;
    private var offset:int;
    private var characterMC:MovieClip;
    public var healthMod:int;
    public var scoreMod:int;

    //CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION
    public function enemy(myBorder:Rectangle, mySkill:int, player:MovieClip)
    {
        //set values
        trace("initialising an Enemy");
        mySkill = 3;
        characterMC = player;
        borderEnemy = new Rectangle(50,180,840,750);
        //setting constraing area
        borderEnemy = myBorder;
        offset = 20;
        //values of lives/scores
        healthMod = -1;
        scoreMod = 0;
        //nasty type linked to mySkill
        charNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (mySkill + 2));
        charSpeed = charNum + 1;
        //what can I hit?
        //eventlistener: starts code when character enters stage
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initEnemy);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);
    }//end function enemy

    //function to initiate enemy
    private function initEnemy(evt:Event):void
    {
        //displaying the enemy frame (appearence) according to charNum
        gotoAndStop(charNum);
        //setting item positon, linked to function
        setPosition();
        //start movement of enemy, linked to function
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemy);
        //remove unneeded listener after initiation
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initEnemy);
    }//end function initEnemy

    //function to set enemy position
    private function setPosition():void
    {
        //setting enemy positions
        //trace("setting enemy position");
        //code to determine enemy direction
        charDir = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        //trace("charDir value is " + charDir);
        //code to determine enemy location (vertically)
        var myRand:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8) * (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) + 2);
        if (charDir < 1)
        {
            //trace("char entering from left");
            //random option 1: character appears from the left
            charDir = 1;
            this.x = borderEnemy.left - offset - myRand;
            this.scaleX = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //trace("char entering from right");
            //random option 2: character appears from the right
            charDir = -1;
            this.x = borderEnemy.right + offset + myRand;
            this.scaleX = -1;
        }
        //set verticle position using myRand
        var myHeight:int = borderEnemy.bottom - borderEnemy.top - offset * 1;
        this.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * myHeight) + borderEnemy.top * 1;
    }//end function setPosition

    //function to move enemies
    private function moveEnemy(evt:Event):void
    {
        if (charDir < 1)
        {
            this.x +=   -  charSpeed - 10;
        }
        else
        {
            this.x +=  charSpeed + 10;
        }
        //reset character as it hits the border
        if (this.x < borderEnemy.left - 40 || this.x > borderEnemy.right + 40)
        {
            setPosition();
        }
    }//end function moveEnemy

    //function to check for collisions between player and enemies
    private function checkCollision(evt:Event):void
    {
        //detecting if enemy has hit the player character
        if (this.hitTestObject(characterMC))
        {
            trace("Hit an enemy");
            MovieClip(root).updateScores(this);
            setPosition();
        }//end if statement
    }//end function checkCollision
    //function to remove enemies from map
    public function removeAsset():void
    {
        // remove event listeners and the item
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);
        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemy);
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        trace("removing the enemies");
    }//end function removeAsset
}//end class
}//end package
```

Item class code (collect)

```
package 
{

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class collect extends MovieClip
{

    private var itemNum:int;
    private var borderCollect:Rectangle;
    private var frameNum:int;
    private var characterMC:MovieClip;
    public var healthMod:int;
    public var scoreMod:int;

    public function collect(myBorder:Rectangle, mySkill:int, player:MovieClip)
    {
        borderCollect = new Rectangle(30,180,870,750);
        characterMC = player;
        healthMod = 0;
        scoreMod = 1;
        //constructor code
        trace("Initialise an Item");
        //constraint area for item spawn
        var borderCollect = myBorder;
        var offset = -200;
        //which item is spawned - based on the player skill variable
        var itemNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * mySkill);
        var frameNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
        //start process once item appears on stage
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initItem);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkItems);
    }//public function "collect" end, what is initiated by the class

    private function initItem(evt:Event):void
    {
        //display frame based on itemNum
        gotoAndStop(frameNum);
        trace("selecting item frames");
        //tun position item function
        setPosition();
        trace("setting item positions");
        //remove no longer needed event listener
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initItem);
    }//function initItem end

    private function setPosition():void
    {
        var myBorder = new Rectangle(50,180,800,500);
        var offset = 100;
        //positioning the Item according to borders
        trace("setting positions for items");
        var myWidth:int = myBorder.right - myBorder.left - offset;
        this.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * myWidth) + myBorder.left * 1;
        var myHeight:int = myBorder.bottom - myBorder.top - offset;
        this.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * myHeight) + myBorder.top * 1;
    }//function setPosition end

    private function checkItems(evt: Event):void
    {
        // hit the character 
        if (this.hitTestObject(characterMC))
        {
            trace("Got an Item");
            MovieClip(root).updateScores(this);
            removeAsset();
        }//end if statement
    }//end function checkCollision

    public function removeAsset():void
    {
        // remove event listeners and the item
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkItems);
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        trace("removing an Item");
    }//end function removeMe

}//class end

}//package end
```

Error (gameover with any items collected)

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at collect/removeAsset()[H:\DIG MEDIA Post CHris\Memento - items added\collect.as:77]
at Memento/clearObjects()[H:\DIG MEDIA Post CHris\Memento - items added\Memento.as:140]
at Memento/gameOver()[H:\DIG MEDIA Post CHris\Memento - items added\Memento.as:165]
at Memento/updateScores()[H:\DIG MEDIA Post CHris\Memento - items added\Memento.as:111]
at enemy/checkCollision()[H:\DIG MEDIA Post CHris\Memento - items added\enemy.as:113]
```

The addItem, addEnemy, addItems and such are also placed in the .fla frames connected to buttons instead of the document class. I know it's bad practice but they've been there since the start and when I tried moving them it caused a lot of issues.

In any case, thanks so much to anyone willing to sift through my (horribly formated) code to find the (likely very stupid) mistake I've made, and again I'm sorry for the massive blocks of code, I'm just not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: What line of code throws those errors?

Comment: @NealDavis I'm sorry, what do you mean by throw those errors? If you're referring to what lines are creating those errors, the debug errors say it's the removeAsset command not working for on the collect.as class (item)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. I see that now.

Comment: You could try `if (this.parent) this.parent.removeChild(this);` and so forth for the other errors.

Comment: amazing, that actually solved the null problem! I don't really understand how that worked though, can I have an explanation as to why the code wouldn't function before?

I can actually get onto working out why the lvlUp function won't work now.

Comment: I'm glad that worked.  I'm sure you'll figure out why.  Regarding your levelUp function, are you certain that the updateScores function is getting called?  If it is, try tracing something like `trace("items:",currentMementos);` within that updateScores function to see if maybe it is going up by 2's or not going up at all etc., or again, maybe the updateScore function isn't getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to look at it more closely to figure out why exactly my solution worked. The essence of it is this: At some point, your element you are trying to remove is either not there, or is no longer attached to a parent. This code will ensure that the instance you are trying to remove exists and has a parent

```
if (this.parent) this.parent.removeChild(this);
```